# Size Limit Error when deploying my Sitecore solution

Tags: powershell

I installed Sitecore 9.0 in my local machine and migrated Sitecore 8.0 to the local Sitecore 9. The migrated Sitecore 9.0 is working without any issue.

While I'm working on packaging local Sitecore 9.0 instance to deploy the package on Azure PaaS Sitecore 9.0 by using Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.0.0, I got this error at Powershell.

It says:

> The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to
>   supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size.

and the error is at line 190.

[image]

Do you have any idea? or Is there another way to migrate local Sitecore 9 to Azure PaaS Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 2):

I got the response from Sitecore that this is registered as a bug in the version 9.0 (initial). I'm not sure this is error as well in 9.0.1 because I raised the issue after update 1 releases.

Sitecore suggested an alternative way for migrating from On-Prem to Azure and here is from Sitecore.

> Unfortunately, overcoming this issue unlikely will help in this specific case, since currently Sitecore XP 9.0 cannot be packaged using Azure Toolkit 2.0 (for now). I'm really sorry for this inconvenience.
>
> As an alternative approach, let me suggest you the following:
>   1. Using Sitecore Azure Marketplace, deploy a clean solution to Azure: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.AppSvc_SiteCore_IFrame 
>   2. Using FTP access, copy custom file-based content to your solution 
>   3. In the Azure SQL Server firewall, allow access for your IP address, via [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) 
>   4. Connect to Azure SQL databases using the SQL Server Management Studio and restore your databases on top of clean ones 
>   As a result, you should get a customized solution (with all your files) that contains the custom content (your databases)

If you use this approach and finish migrating, don't forget to re-build indexes.